# Shopify proxy url not working but unproxied is working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, proxy, shopify-app

My shopify app proxy information:

```
Subpath prefix: apps

Subpath: rma

Host: https://www.example.com/shopdevc/shopifyAPI/
```

If I query the host directly using https://www.example.com/shopdevc/shopifyAPI/apps/rma, it works great.

But, in my React function, querying "/apps/rma" returns

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <script type="module" src="/@vite/client"></script> <script type="module"> import RefreshRuntime from "/@react-refresh" RefreshRuntime.injectIntoGlobalHook(window) window.$RefreshReg$ = () => {} window.$RefreshSig$ = () => (type) => type window.__vite_plugin_react_preamble_installed__ = true </script> <meta charset="UTF-8" /> </head> <body> <div id="app"><!--app-html--></div> <script type="module" src="/src/entry-client.jsx"></script> </body> </html>
```

Is there something wrong with my proxy url or path? My folder structure is

```
"c:\wwwroot\shopDevC\shopifyAPI\apps\rma\index.aspx"
```

where index.aspx is the default document.

My code:

```
function delayed_render(async_fun, deps=[]) {
    const [output, setOutput] = useState();
    useEffect(async () => setOutput(await async_fun()), deps);
    return (output === undefined) ? null : output;
}


function TestAPI() {
    return delayed_render(async () => {
        // const resp = await fetch(`https://www.example.com/shopdevc/shopifyAPI/apps/rma`);    // this works fine
        const resp = await fetch(`/apps/rma`);   //this does not work even though our proxy is set to https://www.example.com/shopdevc/shopifyAPI
        const data = await resp.text();
        return <div>
            <h1> Fetch data from an api in react: {data} </h1>
        </div>;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply bypassed using the shopify proxy and rolled my own in index.js:

```
    app.use(`/a/prx/*`, async function(req, res) {
    const path = req.originalUrl.split(`/`).splice(-1).toString(); 
    var options = {
        method: req.method,
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': req.headers[`user-agent`],
            "X-User-Agent": req.headers[`user-agent`],
            "Shopify-API-Key": process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
            "Shopify-API-Secret": process.env.SHOPIFY_API_SECRET
        }
    };
    const response = await fetch(`${process.env.KP_SHOPIFY_API}${path}/`, options);
    const data = await response.text();
    res.send(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I too have been working on a similar problem today. Almost my exact search phrase `Shopify proxy url not working but unproxied is working`. This is not an answer to your problem but may help you and perhaps others may find this useful. It's the url resolution I think, not your react code.

My skeleton was built with the `shopify-cli`**:** `shopify create app node`.

What I saw in my browser developer window when loading `https://{shop}.myshopify.com/{proxy_prefix}/{proxy_path}/{rest-of-path}` was that assets were requested to the root. `src="/src/entry-client.jsx"` etc. Which was trying to load `https://{shop}.myshopify.com/src/entry-client`. My solution was to replace the root with the full url of my host in the server file `server/index.js`, . The following works for the compiled files in dist (`isProd === true`):

```js
app.use("/*", (req, res, next) => {                                                          
      let host = "";
      let contentType = "text/html";
      if (Object.keys(req.headers).includes("x-forwarded-for")) {
        host = process.env.HOST; // where I actually am
        contentType = "application/liquid"; // to use shop theme wrapper
      };
      let template = fs.readFileSync(
        path.resolve(root, '/dist/client/index.html'),
        'utf-8'
      );
      template = template.replace("/assets", `${host}/assets`); // correct url
      res
        .status(200)
        .set("Content-Type", contentType)
        .send(template);
    });
```

For the development server (the `!isProd` section) more substitutions are required:

```js
        for (const part of ["/@", "/src"]) {
          template = template.replace(part, `${host}${part}`)                                                                                                          
        };
```

And then to allow the string substitutions the `vite.createServer` instance needs to have `middlewareMode: "ssr"` ([Server-Side Rendering](https://vitejs.dev/guide/ssr.html)) which meant that the `react-refresh` code was not injected. So I included this:

```js
        template = template.replace("<!-- react-refresh -->", `
    <script type="module">
    import RefreshRuntime from "${host}/@react-refresh"
    RefreshRuntime.injectIntoGlobalHook(window)
    window.$RefreshReg$ = () => {}
    window.$RefreshSig$ = () => (type) => type
    window.__vite_plugin_react_preamble_installed__ = true
    </script>
        `);
```

On a final note - I'm still trying to figure out how to make the socket `__vite_ping` go to my `HOST`.

Good luck. Ngā mihi nui.

Comment: I simply created my own proxy in apps.jsx

 app.use(`/a/prx/*`, async function(req, res) {
  const path = req.originalUrl.split(`/`).splice(-1).toString(); 
  var options = {
   method: req.method,
   headers: {
    'User-Agent': req.headers[`user-agent`],
    "X-User-Agent": req.headers[`user-agent`],
    "Shopify-API-Key": process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
    "Shopify-API-Secret": process.env.SHOPIFY_API_SECRET
   }
  };
  const response = await fetch(`${process.env.KP_SHOPIFY_API}${path}/`, options);
  const data = await response.text();
  res.send(data);
 });